# VirtualBox Guest Shared Folder Ignoring umask

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders, fstab, umask

I have a folder on my host system (Arch Linux) which is being shared with an Ubuntu VirtualBox guest. Instead of using automount, I am mounting the folder at boot using the following line in my guest's `fstab` file:

```
sharedfolder /var/sharedfolder vboxsf rw,exec,uid=root,gid=mods,umask=0002 0 0
```

The folder is being mounted successfully, and with the proper owner and group, but the permissions are being shown as missing the `w` permission for the group.

The relevant output of `ls -lh` is below:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 root mods 4.0K Jun  1 16:41 sharedfolder
```

whereas I want it to be:

```
drwxrwxr-x  1 root mods 4.0K Jun  1 16:41 sharedfolder
```

I specifically need any user belonging to the group mods to have full permissions in this folder, which is currently not happening.

I have tried using `chmod 775 sharedfolder`, but the permissions do not change, even when running the command with `sudo`.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't immediately understand what @sapphirecat meant... You can change `/etc/fstab` to something like this:

```
sharedfolder /var/sharedfolder vboxsf rw,exec,uid=root,gid=mods,dmode=775,fmode=664  0 0
```

I'm using:

```
share-loc-in-macos    /var/www/html/share-loc-in-debian    vboxsf   defaults,uid=1000,gid=33,dmode=775,fmode=664    0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `umask`, `fmask`, and `dmask` options are applied to the default VirtualBox mode.  (I'm using an OS X host, and my folders mount with `drwx------` permissions, i.e., 700.)

While this can be overridden with the `fmode` and `dmode` options, those will apply to **all** of the files and directories, respectively, regardless of what the execute bit might have been on the host.  Setting and clearing the execute bit in the guest sets or clears the bit on the host, but continues to always show as executable in the guest.

I'm not aware of any way to get the execute bit to reflect the host file's bit in the guest.